# Eclipse becomes unresponsive if used with TESTNG debug option

Tags: eclipse, testng

Eclipse  becomes unresponsive if used with TEST NG debug option.so uanable to use debug option
I am using following versions:
Selenium webdriver - 2.24.1
Testng - 6.02

Any suggestion ?

Thanks,
Fanindra

Comment: You can try updating TestNG plugin.

Comment: Hi,

Below is my configuration but still getting the same issues.console message says "launching abc class (57 % ) and it hangs.

1.Java version - jdk-7u7-windows-x64
2.Eclipse version -64 bit eclipse  - Kepler
3.Testng version - 6.8.0

Let me know if anything else is reqd

Comment: just to add to above list -Selenium webdriver - 2.28.0

Answer (score 1):

Just to update you all…this problem has been solved.

Following three things were done which resulted in solving this problem:

```
   Remove all existing breakpoints
   Removing other versions of testing jars..Keeping only latest one i.e. 6.8 testng jar
   Put the debug value as 

   -Xms1024m

   -Xmx2048m

  In eclipse configuration settings file.
```

Comment: -Xmx2048m in eclipse 32bit doesn't work. Anyone else had found this to solve TestNG hangs in eclipse debugger ?